# "Emacs" before my username in zsh

Tags: zsh, zshrc, oh-my-zsh

I installed zsh, set the oh-my-zsh and then set the powerline
and when I use zsh, then before my name there "emacs". 
It's look like:

**EMACS** > username > ~

How to remove it?

Comment: Is your system by any chance called _EMACS_?

Comment: *powerline* is your *oh-my-zsh* theme? What is the output of `echo $PROMPT`?

Comment: @Adaephon, i have Linux Mint 16. _Powerline_ is a plug-in for zsh. _Oh-my-zsh_ is a theme for zsh. echo $PROMPT give such output:  $($POWERLINE_COMMAND shell left -r zsh_prompt --last_exit_code=$? --last_pipe_status="$pipestatus" --renderer_arg="client_id=$$" --jobnum=$_POWERLINE_JOBNUM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This prompt is generated by powerline. The "**EMACS**" indicates that the currently used keymap is *emacs*.

You can remove it by altering your powerline configuration. General instructions should be available with your powerline installation (or [from the github repository](https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline/blob/develop/docs/source/configuration.rst))

To remove the keymap indicator, you have to either edit the current theme or create a new one. The default theme for shell can be found at `${POWERLINE_CONFIG}/themes/shell/default.json`. You just have do remove the following block from `"segments"->"left"`

```
{
    "module": "powerline.segments.shell",
    "name": "mode"
},
```